# SSRS group header shows on all but last page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have had some trouble getting group headers to show on each page, but the steps to achieve this are well documented on here and elsewhere online, but I have a new problem.

I have a group header that appears on each page except for the last one.

My report is set like this-

```
<group on IDs>
  <group on description>
    <group on desc_num>
      <static>
      <static>
      <static>
  <group on other>
    <static> -- this is my header causing trouble
    <group on other_num>
      <static>
```

in my dataset query, i have something like this:

```
Select 'Description', ROWNUM desc_num, x,y,z, null null etc...
UNION
Select null null null null etc... 'Other',  ROWNUM other_num, a, b, c
```

In my report, i use the group by description to group together all from the first part of the query, and then i group by desc_num so that i can do a keep together so my static rows stay together. I do the same for other.

Each ID can have many descriptions each containing multiple groups of details. They can also have many "others" containing multiple groups of details. The description and other groups can contain several pages worth of data.

For my heading for the other group, I have the advanced properties set to True, After, True for KeepTogether, KeepWithGroup, and RepeatOnNewPage which allows it to show on each page of the other groups.

This works perfectly, except that the other header will not appear on the last page. For one specific id, there are 3.5 pages of "description" group, followed immediately (no page break) by 6 pages of "other" group. The word "Other" shows appropriately at the beginning of the other group halfway down page 4 and at the top of each following page except for on page 10, which only contains a half page.

This header has similar result when there are less pages, it always does not show on the last full page of "Other" group members.

If anyone has any ideas or advice for this, i would greatly appreciate it.